# Finding out values of $k_1$ in a cubic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose a cubic polynomial $$f(x)=x^3+k_1x^2+k_2x+72$$ is divisible by both $x^2+ax+b$ and $x^2+bx+a$ where $a,b,k_1,k_2$ are constants and $a\neq b$ then the question is to find out the value of $k_1$

---

I noticed that $1$ should be a root of the cubic polynomial and $1+a+b=0$.I couldn't proceed after this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then $x-1$ is a factor of both $x^2+ax+b$ and $x^2+bx+a$.
So $x^2+ax+b=(x-1)(x+a+1)$. So $-a-1=b$ is a root, and similarly $a$
is a root. Now $f(x)=(x-1)(x-a)(x-b)$. So can you now see what $k_1$ is?

Comment: From this also $k_2$ can be  calculated by Vieta